# Q: Arrays and Functions Homework

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, int

To put it bluntly, as it stands, I am not very good at coding at this current time.  I am really trying to get these functions completed, I am just having trouble with the execution on some of them.

Basically, there are 10 functions ( 6 of which I have finished? ) that need to be created.
There is an int main() but, besides a string that needs to be fixed, the int main() does not need to be touched.

I will post the program (mostly so you can see my work) in addition to the int main() so that if someone wants to check the intent, they can see it. Even though I have posted the whole program, the only ones that I really want to focus on are the makeUpper, and the functions that have nothing in them because I really don't understand how to copy and edit a string into another array.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

void makeUpper( char orig[], char result[] )
{
/*
        int i = 0;

        while ( str[i] != '\0' )
        {
                if ( str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z' )
                        str[i] = str[i] - 32;

                k++;
        }
*/
}

int countDigit( char str[] )
{
        int i;
        int count = 0;
        int len;

        len = strlen(str);

        for ( i = 0; i < len; i++ )
        {
                if ( i >= '0' && i <= '9' )
                        count++;
        }

        return count;
}

int onlyLetters( char orig[], char letters[] )
{
}

int countOdd( int A[], int N )
{
        int i;
        int odd = 0;

        for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ );
        {
                if ( A[i] % 2 != 0 )
                        odd++;
        }

        return odd;
}

int sumList( int A[], int N )
{
        int i;
        int sum = 0;

        for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ );
                sum = sum + A[i];

        return sum;
}

void addToEach( int A[], int N, int val )
{
        int i;

        for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
                A[i] + val;

        printf("%d", A[i]);
}

void copyNumList( int orig[], int N, int result[] )
{
}

// populate list A with N items, random in range L to H
void fillNumList( int A[], int N, int L, int H )
{
}

// print the list, 10 items per line
void printList( int A[], int N )
{
        int i;

        for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
                printf("%d ", A[i]);

        printf("\n");
}

void rept( int n, char c )
{
        int i;

        for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
                printf("%c", c);

        printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
        char line[100], other[100];
        int i, len;

        printf("Phrase: ");
        fgets( line, 100, stdin );

        // fix the string....
        // ...
//              really, do this
        // ...

        rept(10,'-');
        printf("Orig:  @@%s@@\n", line);

        rept(10,'-');
        makeUpper( line, other );
        printf("toupper: %s\n", other);

        rept(10,'-');
        i = countDigit( line );
        printf("%d digits\n", i);

        rept(10,'-');
        len = onlyLetters( line, other );
        printf("only letters: %s\n", other );
        printf(" new len %d\n", len);

        int nums[30], vals[30];
        int many = 19;

        rept(5, '-');
        fillNumList( nums, many, 3, 11 );
        printList( nums, many );

        rept(5, '-');
        i = countOdd( nums, many );
        printf("%d odd values\n", i);
        rept(5, '-');
        i = sumList( nums, many );
        printf("%d is sum\n", i);

        rept(5, '-');
        copyNumList( nums, many, vals );
        printf("Copy\n");
        printList( vals, many );

        rept(5, '-');
        addToEach( vals, many, 4 );
        printf("Add 4\n");
        printList( vals, many );

        rept(5, '-');
        printf("Orig\n");
        printList( nums, many );
        rept(5, '-');

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oof. First off - [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest). You'd be better served using that space to describe a problem. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. If you have a question, ask. If you have a _task_, as you do, try your best, then ask about the specific place you're stuck.

Comment: Understood, I'll mark it out

Comment: For example, "I really don't understand how to copy and edit a string into another array." is a start of an interesting question (assuming you elaborate what exactly about it you don't understand, and what you tried to do that failed). "Please implement these functions for me" is not. Lastly, one question per question, please.

Comment: I understand and I am very sorry. I'm taking the course online and I don't really have other students I can talk to for testing and exchanging advice.

Comment: While other students certainly help, they're not essential. If you're staying past midnight trying to solve a problem, that's a great time to ask about what you're stuck on on Stack Overflow. Wating till deadline then asking for others to finish it for you, not ideal.

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: You're right. Though, it's not necessarily that I am waiting until the deadline, so much as the professor made 4 assignments all within two days of eachother right before a final. Throughout the semester, he only asked for 1 assignment a week, so I have just been working away at them.

Comment: You should look up the functions in `<ctypes.h>` — they will make functions such as `makeUpper()` easier to write and easier to read.

Comment: Thank you! That seems like it would be very useful!

Comment: I'm really not just looking for CODE PLEASE, but I do appreciate the tip :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the one almost-well-defined question (regarding `makeUpper`):

First, `str` is not a variable. You have `orig` and `result`, and haven't declared `str` anywhere.

Now, if `str` were `orig`, you'd be correctly uppercasing the characters in the original string. However, the task is to leave the original string alone and make an uppercased copy. The former is called "destructive operation" (as the original contents are not preserved); the latter, a "non-destructive operation" (for obvious reasons). Here are the changes needed to make your function non-destructive:

```
void makeUpper( char orig[], char result[] )
{
        int k = 0;

        do
        {
                if ( orig[k] >= 'a' && orig[k] <= 'z' )
                        result[k] = orig[k] - 32;
                else
                        result[k] = orig[k];

        } while ( orig[k++] != '\0' );
}
```

Notice that I iterate and test on `orig`, but assign to `result`.

`onlyLetters` should be similar; but you will need two index variables, not just `k`, since you will want to progress through `orig` and `result` at different pace (you'll only want to copy a character when it's a letter, and you'll only want to progress through `result` when you do a copy - as opposed to `orig`, which you'll always consume one character per loop).

As you have not stated what your misunderstanding is about `copyNumList` and `fillNumList`, I cannot give you any help there.

EDIT: I forgot about the terminator (and didn't test it); thanks Tom Karzes! Because the zero also needs to be copied, your loop is changed from `while (condition) { ... }` to `do { ... } while (condition)` - instead of testing whether we're at end and then doing things if we're not, we'll do the thing first, and only afterwards ask if we're done. This also requires the increment to be done after the test, so `k++` got moved. If this is too weird for you, you can get the same effect like this, by explicitly adding the terminator after the loop is done:

```
void makeUpper( char orig[], char result[] )
{
        int k = 0;

        while ( orig[k] != '\0' )
        {
                if ( orig[k] >= 'a' && orig[k] <= 'z' )
                        result[k] = orig[k] - 32;
                else
                        result[k] = orig[k];

                k++;
        }
        result[k] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: So you are testing the string contents of the orig; considering if there are any lower-case characters. However, within the "if" statement, you are running the operation and setting the result as = to the orig, skipping posting a value into the orig.

The "else" statement is merely in the case of there being no lower-case.

Comment: `result` has nothing; thus, lowercase letters need to be uppercased, non-lowercase letters need to be copied. Thus, the `else` is not a "merely just in case" thing, it is integral to not getting `"ARTIN UTHER ING R"` from `"Martin Luther King Jr."`.

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense. Thank you for the example as well. The professor didn't want us to use do loops, only for and while, so I appreciate the extra example as well.